# Testing Authenticated website with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, mozilla

I am working on a website which is for most part authenticated for users.

Parts of the site are actually available prior to the login for authentication
the rest is all inside a secure website. I am able to test the non-authenticated pieces without any problem. Those features which are inside the website needs be tested and used in C# Selenium with multiple browsers as well as the section which will have the hyperlinks that were tested previously. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is some ideas with code to go with it.
IWebDriver AzimaHome = new Chrome();
AzimaHome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:www.msn.com");

IList terms = AzimaHome.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
terms.First(element => element.Text == "").Click();

This will take me to the main login page.
The next step is User Name and Password Textboxes
Followed by a Database Textbox

```
            Terms.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://qaweb.wptss.com/tools");`
```

UserName = Terms.FindElement(By.Name("UserName"));
                UserName.SendKeys("kf");

```
            Password = Terms.FindElement(By.Name("Password"));
            Password.SendKeys("kfi");

            textBox = Terms.FindElement(By.Name("DSN"));
            textBox.SendKeys("??");enter code here`
```

Comment: The question needs to be a little more specific, possibly broken into different pieces (how to test authenticated services with selenium, how to test in multiple browsers). Asking more specific questions, ideally showing done example of what b you HAVE done, is more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: The screen that I start with is already set to a login screen so when it comes up it goes straight to a login. As well as it has some hyperlinks like privacy, terms and the home page for the company. What I need is that this is that once I have logged in that I need to support all of the ability menu options and other links that are only available in the secured site.

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question. It seems to be too broad for stackoverflow. You may want to do a web search and read some tutorials. Come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said,"I need to support all of the ability menu options and other links that are only available in the secured site."

The code for accessing the elements will remain same. I suggest you to try to check the source code of the page and try to access the elements based on their ID, name or other properties.

If you meet with any issue then you can try to post the part of the source code and your selenium code with which you are having an issue. We will try to look in to it and try to provide you suggestions for it.

Let me know, if I misunderstood anything from your above description. I will try to correct my self. Thanks for your understanding.